# Can't pipe from echo to bash built-in read?

Tags: bash

Say I have a loop that goes through a file line-by-line via `read`. I would like to have both the original line, and the line split into different variables, which `read` does nicely. However, I can't seem to echo a variable, pipe it to `read`, and have the variables populated. Here's a base case:

```
echo "a b c d e f g" | read line
echo "Read obtained: $line"
```

The result:

```
Read obtained:
```

How can I make read do what I want? Or: Why am I wrong to ask read to do this, and what should I do instead?

Comment: Pipelines create a subshell and `read` is a built-in, so it hasn't actually been executed in your top level script/shell.  And also, **[don't use a shell loop to process text!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)**

Comment: Even if `read` were to be able to assign to a variable in the outer scope, your snippet of code is pretty much (but TBH not exactly) the same as a simple assignment: `line="a b c d e f g"`.

Comment: I understand. I was only presenting a minimal case to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `read` read from pipeline as follows; Original [answer by @yardena on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779351/4023950)

```
echo "a b c d e f g" | { read line; echo line=$line; }
```

Comment: Try `echo "$line"` on the next line, i.e. outside your curly braces, to see the problem

Answer (score 0):

the problem is scope. the variable has no value outside the subshell created by the pipe. Instead:

```
while read line; do echo "read obtained: ${line}"; done < <(echo "a b c d e f g")
```

use a loop however you want to. if you want to process text with one, do it.
-C

Comment: You should actually read the linked post thoroughly.  [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)